# Vscodeで、プログラミング言語を変えたい

Tags: python, c, vscode

もともとPythonを入れていて、言語をC言語に変えたいのですがうまくいきません。
ターミナルがPython仕様になっているようです。どうすればうまくいくでしょうか

[image]

Answer (score 1):

右下にPythonと表示されている箇所がありませんか？
そこをクリックすると「言語モードの選択」と表示されて他の言語に変更できると思います

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。言語はかえれたみたいです。ここから、Run build taskをして、start debuggingをしようと思ったら、launch:program "does not exist.というエラーが出てしまいました、、

Comment: Run build task というのは右上のボタンのことですか？

Comment: 真ん中上らへんのターミナルで選べます。Ctrl+Shift+Bです

Comment: VSCode はあくまでエディタであって、言語ごとの設定をしてくれるのは拡張機能、コンパイルをしてくれるのはパソコンにインストールされている各種実行可能ファイルたち、なので、拡張機能の設定や、必要な実行可能ファイルをインストールしてあるかを確認してください。

Comment: エラーについて、[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65943/19110)で新しく質問されたようです。