# VScode でC言語のデバッグができません "launch:program'C:\C\launch.exe'does not exist"

Tags: c, vscode

VScode でC言語の実行のところからデバッグをしようと思ったんですが、以下のエラーが発生してしまい実行できません。

```
launch:program'C:\C\launch.exe'does not exist
```

MinGWをインストールして環境変数PATHも設定追加済みです。
OSはWindows10で、MinGWは公式サイトからインストールしました。インストール対象はmingw-32-base-binのみにチェックを入れました。

編集しようとしているCファイルは、Acer(C:)の中のCという名前で作成したフォルダに.vscode（この中にはlanch.jsonというJSONファイルが入っていました）というファイルフォルダとともに入れてあります。
C/C++ExtensionはVScode内でインストールしてあります。

Comment: VSCode のどの機能を使ってデバッグをしようとしたのか（たとえば、どんな操作をしたのか、など）や、どんな拡張機能をお使いなのかの情報が欲しいです。「編集」機能を使って質問文に追記してくださいませんでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。詳細を付け加えました。このファイルは自分で書き込まなければいけないようなものなのでしょうか。また、どこに存在するべきなのかもよくわかっていません。。

Comment: MinGW を使おうとされているのですか。以下の情報を質問文に付け加えていただけますか？　(1) OS (2) MinGW をどのようにインストールしたか (3) 今編集しようとしている C 言語のファイルはどこに置いてあるファイルか

Comment: これらのQ&Aや解説記事にあるような情報を追記すれば、詳しい回答が付きやすくなるでしょう。[VSCodeでデバックしたいがエラーが出て解決できない。](https://teratail.com/questions/163601) 質問にあるように、`tasks.json`とか`launch.json`を追記してみる。[【VSCode】デバッグ機能を使ってC/C++のデバッグをする](https://mattyan1053.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/08/155228) 解説にあるように、どんな手順で何の作業をしていったかを追記してみる。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージは「`C:\C\launch.exe` が存在しません」というものです。

原因と対処方法は以下のような事になるかと。

- `C:\C\launch.exe` というファイルを作り忘れている (まだコンパイルしていない)。
  -> launch.exeを作ればOK
- launch.exeを `C:\C\` とは異なるフォルダーに作ってしまった。
  -> launch.exeを `C:\C\` に移せばOK